# "Intercepting" user input into text box and removing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, input

I have a text box that I would like to do some validation on. At the moment I have this code:

```
function updateChanger() {

    // Validate input
    var likeMessage = validateInput($("#like").val());

    alert(likeMessage);
}

function validateInput(input) {
    input = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9:\(\/\)\s\.,!~]/g, "");
    return input;
}
```

This successfully trims out unwanted characters in the likeMessage variable, but the character still gets entered into the text box. I would like to stop that from happening.

I know it will have something to do with `$("#like").val()` but the only thing I can think of is just chopping off the end character from the text box value, would this suffice?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the [`keyup` event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), like this:

```
$("#like").keyup(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9:\(\/\)\s\.,!~]/g, ""));
});
```

This checks for and removes invalid characters every time they key lets up, so the invalid character won't ever be left in the box, it gets removed immediately.

Comment: Ah, perfect! It'll only let me accept your answer in about 9 minutes though :) Thanks!